# jQuery hover profile?

Tags: jquery, plugins, hover

How to create the effect like trulia when you hover on the avatar?

http://www.trulia.com/voices/Home_Buying/Why_are_there_only_homes_listed_under_quot_Recen-164127

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery Ajax Tooltip](http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea:

1. Show `div` on [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
2. Load data via [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and append it to `div`
3. Hide `div` on [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into this list, it shows quite a few plugins that creates such tooltips:

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/